# Specificity of Nested CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why "Item One" does not show as orange, below. According to specificity rules, the selector `.one.two`, should have a specificity score of 20 (two classes). `.one li` should have 11 (one class, one element). So it feels like it should show as orange, not blue.

Any idea why it doesn't?

Also, as a side question, why can't I have a space between the `.one` and the `.two` in the `.one.two` selector? That works for Chrome it seems, but not [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_element_pluss).

[Link to specificity calculations](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .one {
      color: red;
    }
    .two {
      color: green;
    }
    .one li {
      color: blue;
    }
    .one.two {
      color: orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="one two">
      <li>Item One</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So it feels like it should show as orange, not blue.
>
> Any idea why it doesn't?

Your `ul` **is** orange. But your `li` is colored blue independently of the color of its parent because you have explicitly targeted it and applied a color to it. It will not inherit its parent's color if you override the implicit `color: inherit`.

> why can't I have a space between the .one and the .two in the .one.two selector?

Because that's a completely different selector. `.one .two` matches a `.two` **inside** a `.one`. `.one.two` (with no space) matches an element that is both `.one` and `.two`.

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div> /* matched by .one .two */
</div>

<div class="one two"></div> /* matched by .one.two */
```

Comment: `<div class="one two three">` does not just look for `.one.two.three` though, right? It seems it also looks for `.one` and `.two` and `.three` independently. Is there some kind of order it searches? I guess it looks for them independently, but not nested.

Comment: You're thinking about this backwards. `<div ...>` does not "look for" `.one.two.three`. The `<div>` is just a static DOM node, sitting there. The CSS *selects* the matching elements via selectors (the `.one.two.three` part) and applies rules to them ( the `color: blue` part). A `.one.two.three` selector will match any combination of those classes on a single element.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is working fine but there is also this css

```
.one li {
  color: blue;
}
```

So your css is applying orange color on `.one.two` but `.one li` css overlapping and showing blue color.

You can add this css if you want orange color on li under `.one.two`

```
.one.two li {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add `li` in the selector after `.one.two`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .one {
      color: red;
    }
    .two {
      color: green;
    }
    .one li {
      color: blue;
    }
    .one.two li {
      color: orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="one two">
      <li>Item One</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```