# Specificity and Inheritance in CSS

Tags: html, css

I asked a slight wrong, but still helpful, question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426167/spesificity-of-nesten-css-selectors/36426240?noredirect=1#comment60467542_36426240). Posting a new one for the sake of keeping it clean.

In the below, could you help me understand why `.one li` wins over `.one .two`, making `Item One` blue instead of pink? According to the rules of specificity ([link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)), two classes nested has a specificity score of 20, while a class and an element has a score of 11. `.one .two` should according to that, win.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .one {
      color: red;
    }
    .one li {
      color: blue;
    }
    .one .two {
      color: pink;
    }
    .one .two .three {
      color: purple;
    }
    .two {
      color: green;
    }
    .one.two {
      color: yellow;
    }
    .two.three {
      color: grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="one">
    <ul class="two">
      <li>Item One</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="three two one">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The same case as in the other question. `.one li` is for the `li` (direct to it) whereas `.one .two` assigns the color to the parent `ul`. Inheritance happens only when the `li` itself doesn't have a color specifically assigned. Specificity calculations apply only when two or more selectors target the same element. Here they are not targeting the same element and hence specificity has no role.

Comment: The accepted answer on your previous question explains why very clearly. Perhaps you should ask for clarification on the points you didn't understand on that answer?

Comment: @Quentin The previous thread does not discuss Inheritance, which is what this particular question addresses.

Comment: Never mind, the previous answer was updated to include info on inheritance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`.one .two` makes your ul pink.
`.one li` makes your li blue.

so you are looking at a blue li on top of a pink ul.