# html does not respect the font-family set in a style

Tags: html, css, inheritance, font-family

I have reduced my problem to a trivial example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        body,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5 {
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif
        }

        body {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a> a simple text w </a>
    <h1> a simple h1 text w </h1>
    <h2> a simple h2 text w </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Which I would expect to produce three lines of *sans-serif* text. The web inspector indicates that all three lines should be `sans-serif`.

Tested on Chromium and Firefox, I get three lines of text, one sans-serif, and two more, for `h1` and `h2` in serif font:

[image]

What is the explanation of this behavior? What is my misunderstanding of the way font appearances are inherited and applied?

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specificity of Nested CSS Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426167/specificity-of-nested-css-selectors)

Answer (score 3):

Since you declared `Times New Roman` for both, the `h1` and the `h2` elements, they both render with this font.

And since the last definition in CSS has a higher order than the first one, the `a` elements inherits the style set for the `body` selector, which is: `sans-serif`.

This is not an issue, it is as expected.

---

If you would wrap the `<a></a>` element inside a (for example) `<h3></h3>`, you will see, that it will inherit the styles from its parent and displays as serif `Times New Roman` as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        body,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5 {
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif
        }

        body {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a> a simple text w </a>
    <h1> a simple h1 text w </h1>
    <h2> a simple h2 text w </h2>

    <h3>
        <a> a simple text w </a>
    </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - I begin to understand. I assumed the first declaration (body, h1,...) would be merged with the second one (body..) but your answer suggest the second replaces the first completely. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Not entirely replaced, in the 2. Declaration you are overriding the properties that are styled in your 1. Declaration. In your case, that that applies to the `font-family: sans-serif`. Any new styling were added normally.

Comment: my issue is with the second line. The inspector says, it inherits from `body` `sans-serf`, but it is clearly shown with a *serif* font. I cannot see, from where it inherits the `serif` property? The same for your example text line 3, wrapped in `hl3`. The inspector saysfor this line `font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
font-size: 18.72px` but shown is serif? I still not understanding why. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Let my first clarify what the property value means, I am not sure if we do talk about the same thing: What you declare, after the comma `,` for a `font-family`, is the fallback value. If for some reason the user viewing the page doesn't have installed the font you specified (`'Times New Roman'`), only then the fallback you specified (`sans-serif`) will be shown. So, when you see a serif font, you are seeing `Times New Roman` because you have installed that font on your machine. If you wouldn't, you would see the rendering in a `sans-serif` font, decided by the OS. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I was indeed completely mistaken in my understanding of what the font-family declaration means. Now it makes all perfect sense! Thank you for your patience!